# Splitting a bibliography: how to overcome Multibib/Latex's file limitation (16 max)

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm writing a thesis where I'm asked to split the bibliography into different sections, and so far I've been using [Multibib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/multibib.html) which was really perfect for what I wanted to do:

```
\newcites{ltex}{\TeX\ and \LaTeX\ References}
...
\bibliographystyleltex{alpha}
\bibliographyltex{lit}
```

But I'm now facing a limitation regarding the number of files I'm allowed to use, as described in the Multibib documentation:

> The tiny \newcites command is not limited to one bibliography. In fact, you
>   can generate as much bibliographies as you like (only limited by the maximum
>   number of TEX’s output files, usually 16).

Is there any way to easily bypass this limitation? (I can't reduce the number of sections, and I would like to keep Bibtex --- AFAIU splitbib doesn't)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), which does a single read of all of the data (at the start of your file). (BTW, you might get more answers at the new TeX-specific site http://tex.stackexchange.com)

Comment: yes indeed, biblatex solved the issue, there is no more limitation; thanks for the stackexchange link, I didn't know it!

Answer (score 0):

*[Bibtopic](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibtopic/)* seems to match what I was looking for, it's even simpler than Multibib!

```
\usepackage{bibtopics}
...
\begin{btSect}{BIB_FILENAME}
\section{SECTION TITLE}
\btPrintAll || \btPrintCited || \btPrintNotCited
\end{btSect}
```

<strike>I'll accept the answer if it works properly within my document.</strike>

EDIT: *Bibtopic* suffers from the same problem as Multibib ... any other solution than copying the .bbl files directly into my latex files?